# Hosting of ajax enabled wcf service in IIS 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7, 64-bit, svc

I have deployed an asp.net mvc application in IIS, The application has been deployed successfully and working fine. I Used ajax enabled wcf service in my application, the problem is when I want to use the method of the service. I get the not found error, but when I browse to see the service it gives the page saying that your service is hosted, I cannot access the methods of the deployed ajax enabled service.. Kindly help me out..

**Things to be noticed..**
My services are hosted as a file with the extension of .svc
I deployed the application on windows server 2008 r2 64 bit, but I configured the application pool to work in 32 bit.
Services are accessible, but the methods of service are not allowed.

Thanks in advance.
Ahsan Nomani.